# Create a differential backup with rsync of a directory on my local drive to another directory on the same drive

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

How can I use rsync (but neither rsnapshot nor rdiff-backup nor any other application) to create a **differential** backup of a directory located on my local drive to another directory located on that same local drive?

F. Hauri posted the following in [an anwser to *How to create a local backup?*](/a/526037):

```
#!/bin/bash
backRepo=/media/mydisk
backSrce=/home/user
backDest=home
backCopy=copy
backCount=9

[ -d "$backRepo/$backDest" ] || mkdir "$backRepo/$backDest"

cd $backSrce || exit 1
rsync -ax --delete --exclude '*~' --exclude '.DStore' . "$backRepo/$backDest/."

cd $backRepo
[ -d "$backCopy.$backCount" ] && rm -fR "$backCopy.$backCount"
for ((i=$backCount;i--;));do
    [ -d "$backCopy.$i" ] && mv "$backCopy.$i" "$backCopy.$((i+1))"
  done
((i++))

cp -al $backDest $backCopy.$i
```

It seems like the above script is fairly close to what I want, but frankly despite spending about an hour studying [Easy Automated Snapshot-Style Backups with Linux and Rsync](http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/) I still only have a vague idea of how to make rsync do what I want.

**Here's my use case:**

I am editing a video locally on my machine. The sum of all of the hundreds of files associated with that video will be less than 5 gb (five gigabytes).

Currently, I use Grsync to back up my internal drive to an external USB drive. Although I actually figured out how to accomplish the identical task using rsync I prefer using Grsync because I merely need to launch it and then click on one button to backup my internal directory containing my video files to my external USB drive. The entire process is silky smooth.

Every few hours, I want a fairly smooth way to back up my the above-mentioned data associated with my video, to my Google Drive account. I don’t mind manually choosing to upload a folder to Google Drive. I actually sort of prefer having to do so because it would help me to ensure the backup was actually being accomplished.

Every few nights before I go to bed, I have been copying the entire folder containing the video files, which contains many gigs of data, up to my Google Drive account.

I prefer differential backups to incremental ones because in case I were to need to restore my data from Google Drive I would likely be able to do so manually without becoming confused.

Please keep in mind that I am certainly not a unix sys admin at a large corporation supporting hundreds of users. I am a merely one guy who wants an easy method, but not necessarily a completely automated method, to back up his data offsite every few hours in case of a catastrophic loss of data, which would be most likely due to the theft of my computer. I am almost certain rsync can do what I want. Therefore, I am reluctant to install another application.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go!

```
#!/bin/bash

# written by strobelight, you know who you are.
# license, MIT, go for it.

me=`basename $0`

EXCLUDES="\
    --exclude '*~'
    --exclude '.DS_Store'
"

CANDIDATES=/tmp/candidates

usage() {
    cat <<EOF

$me last_diff_dir new_diff_dir [ dir_to_copy ]

where:
    last_diff_dir  is the directory containing the last differential
    new_diff_dir   is the directory you want files saved to
    dir_to_copy    is optional and is the directory to copy from (default .)

cd directory_to_backup
Full backup: $me full_back full_back
Diff backup: $me full_back diff_1
Diff backup: $me full_back diff_2

EOF
    exit 1
}

get_dir() {
    HERE=`pwd`
    cd $1
    x=`pwd`
    cd $HERE
    echo $x
}

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    usage
fi

LAST_DIR="$1"
NEW_DIR="$2"
DIR_TO_COPY="${3:-.}"

mkdir -p "$LAST_DIR" || exit 1
mkdir -p "$NEW_DIR" || exit 1

[ -d "$LAST_DIR" ] || usage
[ -d "$NEW_DIR" ] || usage
[ -d "$DIR_TO_COPY" ] || usage

LAST_DIR=`get_dir "$LAST_DIR"`
NEW_DIR=`get_dir "$NEW_DIR"`
DIR_TO_COPY=`get_dir "$DIR_TO_COPY"`

# get list of what's different
eval rsync -v --dry-run -axH --delete --update $EXCLUDES "$DIR_TO_COPY/" "$LAST_DIR" | awk '
    /building file list/ { next }
    /^$/ {next}
    /bytes.*received/ { nextfile }
    {
        for(i=5;i<NF;i++) {
            printf("%s ",$i)
        }
        printf("%s\n",$NF)
    }
    ' | sed 's:/$::' > $CANDIDATES
#cat $CANDIDATES

# use list to backup 
eval rsync --files-from=$CANDIDATES -lptgoDxH --delete $EXCLUDES ${DIR_TO_COPY}/ $NEW_DIR
```

For example, my current directory has 3 8k files:

```
$ ls -1sk
total 24
 8 seg1
 8 seg2
 8 seg3
```

My full backup doesn't yet exist, let's call that directory full_bak

```
ls ../full_bak
ls: ../full_bak: No such file or directory
```

First we need a full backup from which to do differentials.  I've copied the script to my $HOME/bin directory as test123.sh.  When both args are the same, that's essentially performing a full backup.

```
$HOME/bin/test123.sh ../full_bak ../full_bak
```

script outputs

```
.
seg1
seg2
seg3
```

Now look at ../full_bak

```
$ ls -1sk ../full_bak
total 24
 8 seg1
 8 seg2
 8 seg3
```

Make some changes

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=seg2 bs=512 count=11
```

Confirm there are differences:

```
$ diff -q . ../full_bak
Files ./seg2 and ../full_bak/seg2 differ
```

Now create a differential

```
$ $HOME/bin/test123.sh ../full_bak ../differential1
seg2
```

Look at differential having just the file thats different from the last full backup

```
$ ls -1sk ../differential1/
total 8
 8 seg2
```

Make another change

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=seg4 bs=512 count=10
```

Check what's different

```
diff -q . ../full_bak
Files ./seg2 and ../full_bak/seg2 differ
Only in .: seg4
```

and see we have a new file that's not in our full backup, and a changed file from before.

Do another differential to another directory

```
$ $HOME/bin/test123.sh ../full_bak ../differential2
.
seg2
seg4
```

and see the new differential has the 1st differential as well as the new file

```
$ ls -1sk ../differential2
total 16
 8 seg2
 8 seg4
```

[Differential Backups](http://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/difference-differential-incremental-backup/)

Here's a fullbackup wrapper using test123.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

FULLDIR=/media/mydisk/home
SRCDIR=/home/user

$HOME/bin/test123.sh $FULLDIR $FULLDIR $SRCDIR
```

Here's a differential script creating sub directories based on the hour:

```
#!/bin/bash

FULLDIR=/media/mydisk/fullbackup/home
DIFFDIR=/media/mydisk/differentials/home
SRCDIR=/home/user
DIFFSUB=`date '+BAK_%H'`

$HOME/bin/test123.sh $FULLDIR $DIFFDIR/$DIFFSUB $SRCDIR
```

Comment: Hi @Strobelight,

Thank you very much.

I spent about half an hour trying to understand what to do and trying to do it, but I failed.

I saved your script as “testing123.sh” in my home directory. I navigated to Properties–>Permissions for testing123.sh and checked the check box next to “Allow this file to run as a program.”

In my home directory I created these directories: last_diff_dir, new_diff_dir, and dir_to_copy. I put a file into dir_to_copy. I ran testing123.sh. Then I checked new_diff_dir. It was empty.

I hope you will help me.

Thanks,

Comment: Just in case the comma appended to your name in the comment immediately above prevents you from being notified, I added this comment without the comma.

Comment: Hi @Yekutiel, based on your comments it would appear you're using windows and not linux.  The script must be run via command prompt. Running the script without args shows help. You don't need to create the directories it needs. The help shows some usage. You need to create a full backup at least once, and that's done by passing in the same directory as the 1st 2 args. The 3rd arg is the directory you want to back up and is optional since it uses current directory by default. The 1st 2 args should not be directories within the backed up directory. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @strobelight. Thanks for your prompt and detailed reply. I'm running Linux (GalliumOS 2.0 runs on top of Xubuntu). I am still confused. I often run... #!/bin/sh
gnome-screensaver-command --lock... from a GUI similar to the manner I indicated running testing123.sh. I make rsync backups to my external USB using an app called Grsync. In Grsync I can choose to view the following... rsync -r -t -v --progress --delete -s /home/y/test/input /home/y/test/output... and then copy and paste to a Terminal. But I prefer to use a GUI. Please ELI5 with a hypothetical example from start to finish. Thanks!

Comment: I want to clarify my penultimate comment. I don't need a GUI for the ELI5 hypothetical I requested. Instead I will gladly run them in a Terminal. I can get by ok with a CLE. But GUIs simply work better for my mind because although I think in a precise logical manner, I don't think "in math", I think "in pictures." It used to drive the devs I worked with crazy. They would say something like "2 + 2 =4". Then I would reply, "Oh. I see. If you have two trees and two more trees then you have a total of four trees. Are they standing alone or in a forest?" They would say, "Yes. 2 + 2 =4"

Comment: I've included an example usage in my answer.

Comment: @Yekutiel I've added two wrappers that could be called from your gui.

Comment: Hi @strobelight. Wow! Thanks again for all of your help :) I have spent the last few hours trying but failing to run your script properly. I posted "01 Screencast for stroblight created by Yekutiel.mp4" to ... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-7ZTNl-VFIMakc3aFo2TlRRQkk/view?usp=sharing ... When you have a chance please take a look at it. I am excited about testing out the wrappers!

Comment: @Yekutiel had a look at your video.  I managed to get it to stop right at the beginning, and the problem is that the script for some reason cannot write into the /tmp directory. This is usually not a problem on linux machines.

Comment: Hi @strobelight, Thanks for updating me quickly! The following might not be technically feasible. I had initially considered that  **rsync -r -t -v --progress --delete -s /home/y/input /home/y/output** partially does what I want by writing changes made within "input" to "output". Therefore, I had wondered if—instead of writing those changes to "output"—rsync might be able to be configured to write those changes to a different directory, for example, "differential_backup"? After all, conceptually—though perhaps not technically—my need is similar to an “off-the-shelf” rsync solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Yekutiel sure you can tell rsync to send to a different directory with the `--backup` and `--backup-dir=new_dest_directory` options but this will do an incremental backup, not the differential you desired. My script does what you want. You make a full backup of the inputs directory first, then all the other times you make a differential backup where the input dir is compared to the full backup, and only what's changed gets copied to the output dir. You only need to adjust my CANDIDATES variable to point somewhere you have write permission. I still think you're not on linux as tagged. ;-)

Comment: Hi @strobelight, Thanks for your quick response and for the information about '--backup'. Initially devs often incorrectly surmise that I am a "typical suit" and therefore typically incorrectly attribute my allegedly false technical assertions to PEBCAK. If I can furnish you with reasonable proof that I am indeed running Linux, would you agree to you create a screencast for me in which you provide me with a hypothetical example of how to use your script? If you haven't created a screencast before, I can provide you with some helpful links. Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: Hi @strobelight, I created `rsync -r -t -v --progress --delete -s --backup --backup-dir=/home/y/backup /home/y/input /home/y/output` . If I were use that script carefully—despite my tendency to be careless—I suppose it would meet my requirements. If I were to delete `/home/y/backup` from my local drive immediately after manually copying it to Google Drive, then ran the script once, then worked on my video editing throughout the day, then ran the script a second time, and then immediately manually uploaded `/home/y/backup` to Google Drive.... **This comment is part 1 of 2.**

Comment: **This comment is part 2 of 2.**  ...I think I would be uploading a differential backup vis-à-vis the full backup I had, let’s imagine, uploaded previously to Google Drive, say a week or two before.

Remember, backing up my files to Google Drive is currently a manual process for me. I am not likely to completely automate that process. I don’t want something invasive like a Dropbox client running on my machine and I don’t want to connect to a standard remote server, because Google Drive is free and apparently extremely reliable. I will be offline until Sunday. Thanks again!

Comment: Bump @strobelight.

Comment: Nothing more to add.

Comment: You asserted, "I still think you're not on linux as tagged. ;-)"  Then I responded to that assertion. But you have not yet responded to my response. Thanks!

Comment: well then your linux is messed up if the script can't create files in /tmp. Clean up /tmp or make it writeable to all (as it should be) or change the CANDIDATES variable to point to somewhere you have write permission or is not full.

Comment: Hi @strobelight, Thanks for your response and suggestions. I was not really sure what to do. I took a shot in the dark and just ran a simple test by creating a file called **test1.txt** in **/home/y/**. Then I ran `mv /home/y/test1.txt /tmp` It ran without errors. Then I went to **/tmp**,  opened the file **test1.txt**, and was able to view it properly as a text file. If you would like I will gladly create a screencast for you. I verified my disk is not full I don't know how to clean up /tmp which only has 2 other folders and 2 other files which take up a sum total of less than 10k. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @strobelight I realized restricting rsync to a particular time would satisfy my requirements. Therefore, I searched on Google for "**rsync based on time**" I found  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1837771 which has this `$ find . -mtime +3 -type f -print0 | rsync -0v --files-from=- ~/source ~/destination` I will probably use `-mtime -0.75` (18 hours =0.75*24 hours ) after I am done working for the day. Then I will back up **~/destination** to Google Drive. This will allow me to do what I want: backup changes I have made each day. Thanks again for spending your time to help me out!

Comment: Hi @strobelight I placed the script in my penultimate comment into **/etc/cron.hourly** to decrease the chances of human error. Of course I will still need to manually upload my backups to Google Drive. Thanks!